# How can I simplify this methods expression parameters?

Tags: c#, selenium, lambda, functional-programming, expression

Is there anyway I can change this method to not need the object but just pass a parameter expression:

```
protected void FillInTextFor<T>(T obj, Expression<Func<T, object>> property)
{
    var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)property.Body;
    var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;
    // read value with reflection
    var value = (string)propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
    // use the name and value of the property
    FillInText(propertyInfo.Name, value);
}

    protected void FillInText(String elementId, String text)
    {
        VerifyElementPresent(elementId);
        Driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementId)).Clear();
        Driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementId)).SendKeys(text);
    }
```

Called like
`var personToCreate = new PersonBuilder().RandomFirstName().Build();
FillInTextFor(personToCreate, a => a.FirstName);`

I'd like to just be able to say `FillInTextFor(_ => personToCreate.FirstName);` or something similar

We are trying to make helper methods for Selenium tests. I want to pass an object and select a property and it will automatically use the name of the property as the element id, and the text as the value to string.

Comment: I don't think so as you need your object here -> "var value = (string)propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);" And method you would like to achieve would only pass string to this method, so you'll be missing reference to obj.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an overload like this :

```
protected void FillInTextFor<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
    var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)property.Body;
    var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;
    var compiled = property.Compile();
    var value = compiled();
    FillInText(propertyInfo.Name, value as string);
}
```

And call it using :

```
var personToCreate = new PersonBuilder().RandomFirstName().Build();
FillInTextFor(() => personToCreate.FirstName);
```

Comment: Thanks works great. Don't suppose you have any idea how I could get something similar to take the value but allow me to do something e.g. we have to format DateTime to shortdatetimestring. If I pass in FillInTextFor(() => personToCreate.DateOfBirth.Value.ToShortDateString()) that obviously fails.

Comment: You would have to investigate the expression.